# How I can randomize the content of a text file?

Tags: vb.net, random, text-files

I need to randomize ALL the lines inside a text file and then save the unsorted lines by replacing the same text file.

How I can do all that?

Comment: Do you need a code sample or a pseudo code?

Comment: I'm begineer so i need a full sample, but if you only can give me a pseudo code i can do a try myself... thankyou for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another take on it:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub CreateFile(destFile As String)
        Using sw = New StreamWriter(destFile)
            For i = 1 To 200
                sw.WriteLine("Line " & i.ToString)
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

    Function RandomList(nNumbers As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
        ' generate a List of numbers from 0..nNumbers-1 in a random order.
        Dim ns As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim rnd As New Random
        For i = 0 To nNumbers - 1
            ns.Insert(rnd.Next(0, i + 1), i)
        Next
        Return ns
    End Function

    Sub RandomiseFile(srcFile As String)
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(srcFile)
        Dim nLines = lines.Count
        Dim randomNumbers = RandomList(nLines)
        ' use a temporary file in case something goes wrong so that
        ' the original file is still there.
        Dim tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName()
        ' output the lines in a random order.
        Using sw = New StreamWriter(tmpFile)
            For i = 0 To nLines - 1
                sw.WriteLine(lines(randomNumbers(i)))
            Next
        End Using
        File.Delete(srcFile)
        File.Move(tmpFile, srcFile)
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim fileToUse As String = "C:\temp\makerandom.txt"
        CreateFile(fileToUse)
        RandomiseFile(fileToUse)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thankyou, i've created the module, but please can you tell me now the command to call that module? (i'm so noob, sorry)

Comment: @ElektroHacker That was a complete program which will work if you create a new Console Application project. The only parts you need are the RandomiseFile and RandomList methods, which do not need to be in a module. All you have to do is use `RandomiseFile("yourFilenameGoesHere")`. Does that make it clear?

Comment: I'm impressed, then you gived me a 2in1 tool, i want to compile the console tool too, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim filepath as String = "text_path"
Dim arr() As String = File.ReadAlllines(filepath)
Dim a As Random
Dim b(str.Length) As Integer
Dim result=1, c As Integer

    File.Delete(filepath)
Dim f As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(filepath)

    For i = 0 To str.Length
    while(result)
        result = 0
        c = a.Next(0, str.Length)
        For j = 0 To b.Length
            If b(j) = c Then result = 1
        Next
    end while
        f.WriteLine(arr(c))
    Next
    f.Close()
```

Comment: There is also a File.ReadAllLines().

Comment: But if you use ReadAllLines, you won't have to split it into your array, it returns the array for you.

Comment: sorry but the debugger says: "Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String'." at: "Dim b(Str.Length) As Integer", and if I change "str.lenght" with an "8", the code deletes all the content of the textfile, why i can do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it:

```
Dim linesList As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines("filepath"))
Dim newLinesList As New List(Of String)
Randomize()
While linesList.Count > 0
  Dim randomIndex As Integer = Math.Floor(Rnd() * linesList.Count)
  newLinesList.Add(linesList(randomIndex))
  linesList.RemoveAt(randomIndex)
End While
IO.File.WriteAllLines("filepath", newLinesList.ToArray)
```

Comment: thankyou, seems easy, but it says: "Property access must assign to the property or use its value." at line "randomize()", how I can resolve it?

Comment: @ElektroHacker: shows no compile errors for me. What's the version of your environment?

Comment: thanks for reply, i'm using VS2012, it's a winform, windows 7

Comment: @ElektroHacker: can you post your project? [Here is how it looks on my side](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?md1mbo0073krufj).