# how i can shuffle or randomize all words in textfile?

Tags: c#, vb.net, random, text-files

i need to randomize or shuffle all words in textfile.

for example in my textfile i have following words

```
hello world i have good one
today is good day
it good to see you
all that kind thing world 
boy man women girl
```

and after shuffle or randomize i want to get result like this one

```
is see kind boy today
world all hello women
man that to you day
girl it i one good
have thing world
```

how i can do in vb.net? thanks in advance

---

resolved
        Module Module1

```
        Sub Main()
            Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\nice.txt")
            Dim outputData As String = RandomizeWords(lines)

            IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\nice123.txt", outputData)
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub

        Private Function RandomizeWords(lines() As String) As String

            Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
            Dim newList As New List(Of String)

            For Each line In lines
                Dim orderedWords() As String = line.Split(" "c)
                Dim randomizedWords = From n In orderedWords Order By Guid.NewGuid() Select n

                newList.AddRange(randomizedWords)
            Next

            Dim wordCount As Integer = 0

            For i = 0 To newList.Count - 1
                Dim randomIndex As Integer = New Random().Next(0, newList.Count - 1)

                If wordCount = 4 Then
                    sb.AppendLine(newList(randomIndex))
                    wordCount = 0
                Else
                    sb.Append(newList(randomIndex) & " ")
                End If

                newList.RemoveAt(randomIndex)

                wordCount += 1
            Next

            Return sb.ToString()
        End Function
    End Module
```

Comment: What have you tried? Try it yourself and if you get stuck  come back with a specific question. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Randomizing anything is quite easy. Start by breaking down a list / array with the words. Next steps should be very obvious.

Comment: i never request coding for me!. i referenced here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499409/how-i-can-randomize-the-content-of-a-text-file

Comment: randInputKeyword = RandomClass.Next(1, 10)
                    Dim alrInputedKey As Boolean = False

                    For Each s As String In strarr

                        Try

                            str.Append(s)
                            If randInputKeyword = cnt And alrInputedKey = False Then
                                str.Append(" " & TextBox3.Text & " ")
                                alrInputedKey = True

Comment: this is what i did until now

Comment: @softfx add all of your code to the question not in a comment.  Your question having shown no effort in trying to code it yourself makes it look like a coding request.

Comment: deathismyfriend, how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499409/how-i-can-randomize-the-content-of-a-text-file thread? he is also no effort anything such like me. but nobody say anything but why many people blame me? do not treat me as differenciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extract each separate word as a string and add it to a string array.
2. Shuffle your string array.
3. Print out the words in your array in their new shuffled order.